# Role distribution with springboot keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, keycloak

I made my keycloak configuration so that some endpoints are only accessible when you have the admin role.
This works for the endpoint "/statistics/FillLevel/**" which is only accessible with the admin role, but it does not work for the endpoint "/pairing". The "/pairing" endpoint should be accessible with the admin role, but users with this role can't access it. What could be causing this? I have verified that the user has the administration role.
The JWT token that is generated presents no problems as it is directly validated in postman.
why does it work for one and not the other?

'''

```
 package com.icon.waterstation.config;

 import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
 import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
 import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
 import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
 import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
 import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
 import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
 import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
 import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

 @KeycloakConfiguration
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
 @Import(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.class)
 public class securityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
/**
 * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
 */
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new KeycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}

/**
 * Defines the session authentication strategy.
 */
@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/pairing").hasRole("admin")
            .antMatchers("/statistics/FillLevel/**").hasRole("admin")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}

}
```

'''